# Difficulty in dissolving scotch tape

Tags: experimental-physics, graphene, nanoscience

The scotch tape peeling of graphene is the classical way to do it. But I am having difficulties in dissolving the scotch tape gum and it is giving noise in the Raman signal. How can I transfer the graphene sheets onto a glass slide and how to dissolve the gum completely? Thank you

Comment: I did a lot of graphite peeling this way, and found this to be helpful: pour some Goo Gone into a small beaker, sink your tape under the surface, and run thevbeaker throug an ultrasonic cleaner, with a water or oil bath for coupling, 20 minutes or so. Then repeat with the debris in acetone.

Comment: Have you tried ethanol? IIRC the gum is a crosslinked hydrocarbon called polyisobutylene or something similar. It isn't soluble in ethanol but ethanol preferentially wets many surfaces and will cause the PIB to dewet and come off the surface. It works well on glass but I've never tried it on graphene.

Answer (score -1):

WD40 or DW40 dissolves tape gum easily.